# Error at start up in Grails

Tags: grails, plugins

```
An error occurred installing the plugin [yui-minify-resources-0.1.5]: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Owner\.grails\2.2.4\projects\LCM_A20298819\plugins\yui-minify-resources-0.1.5\lib\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

I saved my project and went to launch it and have run into this error.  It seems that no matter what I do I can not clear it.  I want to get rid of the plugin as it is depricated.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the S.O. locks the file (probably when you run some IDE like GGTS).

When it happens to me in Windows, I close the IDE and manually remove the plugin folder, in your case `C:\Users\Owner\.grails\2.2.4\projects\LCM_A20298819\plugins\yui-minify-resources-0.1.5\`.

Comment: Eclipse is infamous for locking files, especially on Windows, which is why I use neither.

Comment: I had used netbeans in the past.  THis is my first go round with eclipse.  What do you suggest using?

Comment: @Gregg Yeah, I switched to Linux. The Java in general seems to respond a lot better.

Comment: @tomsimo You can try [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html)